# How to resolve webservice issue in iis 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have a website set up in iis 7.0 on my local win 7 machine.  Within this are several webservices - they all can be accessed fine, and I can test this access by going to a browser and checking at http://localhost/test/service.svc.  This works fine.  I'm not trying to recreate this environment on VM with win server 2012 R2, and iis 8.5.  I've set up everything identically, except then navigating to the url above returns on the 1k tb inside the actual service.src as if I opened it in notepad.  If I try to add a reference to this service in VS, I get a better error and one that is related to the mime type for svc.  Here's an example.

Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'file Extension' set to '.svc'.

Based on this issue, I then found a reference to needing to add something along the lines of  to my config file which I do.

Now here's the interesting part.  If I remove any references to the svc mime type in iis in both the server and the site, I receive a 404 not found error when trying to run a service.  If I use the example above to add this with the config file, I receive a duplicate.  If I take out the above example, and enter the mime type in either the server or the site, I then get a duplicate as well.  I also found mention to this, and it seems there is some work around involving             before the config inclusion as referenced above.

What's driving me the most crazy is that non of this is an issue on my local iis 7 machine.  Does anyone have any suggestions, I'm floundering.

Comment: Have you checked the event logs in the win server? Can you find any errors logged? Also first check the service locally within the server before trying to access remotely.